# How to extend a line to touch a polygon?

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to extend line to touch polygon
Create line and polygon line and polygon 
Here is my solution to "stretch and trim".
Turned out a bit trickier than the first "solution" I offered initially.
I also included cases for horizontal and vertical lines.
My example I think covers *all* cases (direction of lines)
I have the coding very simple , no effort to make it more efficient

```
library(sf)
#
s1 <- rbind(c(1, 2), c(2, 3))
ls1 <- st_linestring(s1)
s2 <- rbind(c(2, 2), c(1, 3))
ls2 <- st_linestring(s2)
s3 <- rbind(c(2, 2), c(1, 1))
ls3 <- st_linestring(s3)
s4 <- rbind(c(1, 2), c(2, 1))  # VERTICAL LINE
ls4 <- st_linestring(s4)

vl <- rbind(c(2.5, 2), c(2.5, 3))
svl <- st_linestring(vl)

hl <- rbind(c(0.5, 0.5), c(1, 0.5))
shl <- st_linestring(hl)

line <- st_multilinestring(list(ls1, ls2, ls3, ls4, svl, shl))
p1 <- rbind(c(0, 0), c(1, 0), c(3, 2), c(2, 4), c(1, 4), c(0, 0))
pol <- st_polygon(list(p1))
#
(
  plot1 <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = ls1, col = 'red', size = 2) +
    geom_sf(data = ls2, col = 'darkred', size = 2) +
    geom_sf(data = ls3, col = 'blue', size = 2) +
    geom_sf(data = ls4, col = 'darkblue', size = 2) +
    geom_sf(data = svl, col = 'green', size = 2) +
    geom_sf(data = shl, col = 'green', size = 2) +
    geom_sf(data = pol, fill = NA)
)
```

[image]

```
####################### Function

line_stretchntrim <- function(line, polygon) {
  if (st_crs(line) != st_crs(polygon))
    return("CRS not matching")
  bb <- st_bbox(polygon)
  bbdiagLength <-
    as.numeric(sqrt((bb$xmin - bb$xmax) ^ 2 + (bb$ymin - bb$ymax) ^ 2))
  xy <- st_coordinates(line)[, 1:2]
  npairs <- nrow(xy) / 2
  etline <- NULL
  for (i in 1:npairs) {
    ii <- (i - 1) * 2 + 1
    x <- as.numeric(xy[ii:(ii + 1), 1])
    y <- as.numeric(xy[ii:(ii + 1), 2])
    dxline <- diff(x)
    dyline <- diff(y)
    d <- sqrt(dxline ^ 2 + dyline ^ 2)
    scale <- abs(as.numeric(bbdiagLength)) # * extra if need be
    signx <- sign(dxline)
    signy <- sign(dyline)
    theta <- atan(dxline / dyline)
    #  expand
    if (signy == 1) {
      dx1 <-  -sin(theta) * scale #* d
      dy1 <-  -cos(theta) * scale #* d
      dx2 <-    sin(theta) * scale #* d
      dy2 <-    cos(theta) * scale #* d
    }
    if (signy == -1) {
      dx1 <-    sin(theta) * scale# * d
      dy1 <-    cos(theta) * scale# * d
      dx2 <-  -sin(theta) * scale# * d
      dy2 <-  -cos(theta) * scale# * d
    }


    ## Cases when dxline == 0 or dyline == 0
    # dxline == 0
    if ((dxline == 0) * (signy == -1)) {
      dx1 <-  0
      dy1 <-  cos(theta) * scale# * d
      dx2 <-  0
      dy2 <-  -cos(theta) * scale# * d
    }

    if ((dxline == 0) * (signy ==  1)) {
      dx1 <-  0
      dy1 <-  -cos(theta) * scale# * d
      dx2 <-  0
      dy2 <-    cos(theta) * scale# * d
    }
    if ((signx == 1) * (dyline == 0)) {
      dx1 <-  -sin(theta) * scale# * d
      dy1 <-  0
      dx2 <-    sin(theta) * scale# * d
      dy2 <-  0
    }

    if ((signx == -1) * (dyline == 0)) {
      dx1 <-    sin(theta) * scale# * d
      dy1 <-  0
      dx2 <-  -sin(theta) * scale# * d
      dy2 <-  0
    }


    x1 <- x[1] + dx1
    y1 <- y[1] + dy1
    # second point shift
    x2 <- x[2] + dx2
    y2 <- y[2] + dy2
    # construct spatial line
    sline <- st_linestring(matrix(c(x1, y1, x2, y2),
                                  byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2))
    slineSf <- st_sf(geom = st_sfc(sline), crs = st_crs(polygon))
    # Now trim to polygon
    stline <-  st_intersection(slineSf, polygon)

    etline <- if (i == 1)
      stline
    else
      rbind(etline, stline)
  }
  etline
}


stretched_line <- line_stretchntrim(line, pol)
#

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = pol, fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = line, size = 2) +
  geom_sf(data = stretched_line)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to extend it until one end touches the polygon or both? Is your line feature *always* going to have two vertices? Is the polygon always a single ring or can it be a multipolygon?

Comment: Hi @Spacedman. Thanks for your response. The line will *only* have two vertices.  The situation will present a couple of ways.  1. the line will be entirely within the polygon so both ends needs to be extended to touch the polygon and 2. the line will cross the polygon but needs to be trimmed (intersection) on the end laying outside the polygon but extended on the end inside the polygon.  My current solution is just to scale the line by some guessed amount that is likely to extend over the polygon on both ends  and then trim. This appears like a clumsy way,

Comment: And sorry @Spacedman to answer the question about the polygon, it will only be the one polygon. But we will have multiple lines.

Comment: extend-and-trim was the approach I was thinking of. I don't think its clumsy at all. The scale factor should be easy enough to get from the bounding box of the polygon. Have you coded this? Could you add the code to your question?

Comment: @Spacedman . Give me a day and I'll clean it up and post.

Comment: I have corrected my first "solution" ,  It seems robust now.